# Porque desaparecen los encabezados establecidos en el .htaccess de CORs en Angular

Tags: angular, angular7, cors

Resulta que añado en el servidor en el fichero **.htaccess** una directiva Header 'set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"'. Cuando accedo a la app, sino estoy logado redirige a DNS/login  y la cabecera esta (https://securityheaders.com), En cuanto me logo desaparece, es decir cuando la url es solo el DNS desaparece la cabecera. Uso angular router y:

```
{ path: 'login', component: LoginCliComponent }
{ path: '', component: HComponent, canActivate: [LogInGuard] },
{ path: '**', component: HComponent, canActivate: [LogInGuard] },
```

Por tanto cuando hago alguna integración que no sea  HttpClientModule me salta el '...has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource' sobre todo en integraciones de pago con tarjeta que añades iframes con llamadas externas.
¿Alguna idea de que me falta?

```
Angular CLI: 7.3.0
Node: 14.18.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 7.2.3
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.13.0
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.13.0
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.13.0
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.13.0
@angular-devkit/core              7.3.0
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.3.0
@angular/cli                      7.3.0
@ngtools/webpack                  7.3.0
@schematics/angular               7.3.0
@schematics/update                0.13.0
rxjs                              6.4.0
typescript                        3.1.1
webpack                           4.29.0
```

Comment: Los problemas de CORS son del lado del servidor no de Angular. Replantea tu pregunta porque con lo que expones no es suficiente para entender el problema.

Comment: Nuestra app crea un servicio y llama a una api de un tercero, para el pago de de dicho servicio. Al hacer la llamada nos da un problema de CORS, ya que ellos no devuelven ninguna cabecera. Nuestras llamadas van con cabeceras pero al integrar sus formularios en un iframe nuestro, las siguientes llamadas js van sin cabeceras. No se si se entiende el problema

Comment: Añade la explicación a la pregunta, puedes [edit] y añadir es escenario que genera el problema

Answer (score 0):

> probaste añadir otras reglas?

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
header("Allow: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
if($method == "OPTIONS") {
    die();
}
```

Comment: Si, al final siempre que no intervenga por el medio 'canActivate' las cabeceras están o eso creo.

Aquí se ven las cabeceras de una petición https://dns/login

Esta es la cabecera de la petición http://dns

Comment: probaste modificar { path: '**', component: HComponent, canActivate: [LogInGuard] }? parecería que el problema esta del lado de las reglas para las rutas

Comment: { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }

Comment: Sigue igual, la ruta **`https://dns`** no tiene cabeceras.

Comment: no se si es tu caso ?-->necesitaremos añadir en la raíz de nuestra aplicación el archivo .htaccess con el siguiente contenido : vinculo-->https://ekiketa.es/htaccess-para-angular/

Comment: Lo siento pero no lo comprendo.

Comment: siento no poder ayudarte vi en un comentario en el cual que te solicitaron mas datos para poder comprender el problema